# Harmonic Oscillator not getting oscillations

Tags: c++, simulation

I am writing a harmonic oscillator program , but it does an exponential decay instead and I am not sure why. I have the code below. I use `F= -k x` and `F = m a`

I assume `m = 1` and `k = 1`, so `a = -x`

So my equations to find velocity  and position are

`v(t) = v(t-dt) - x(t-dt) * dt`

`x(t) = x(t-dt) + v(t-dt) * dt`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

The code associated with this is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

double updateX(double intialV, double intialX, double step);
double updateV(double intialV, double intialX, double step);

int main()
{
    long double position[2];long double velocity[2];
    position[0] = 0.0; velocity[0] = 1.0; double time = 0.0; double step = .1;
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("velo1.dat");

    outputFile << time << " " << position[0] << " " << velocity[0] << "\n";

    for(int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
    {
        time = i * step;

        velocity[1] = updateV(velocity[0], position[0], step);
        position[1] = updateX(velocity[0], position[0], step);

        outputFile << time << " " << position[1] << " " << velocity[1] << "\n";

        velocity[0] = velocity[1];
        position[0] = velocity[1];

    }
    return 0;

    outputFile.close();
}

double updateX(double intialV, double intialX, double step)
{
    double stuff =(intialX + intialV * step); 
    return stuff;
}

double updateV(double intialV, double intialX, double step)
{
    double stuff =  (intialV - intialX * step) ;
    return stuff;
}
```

Comment: `position[0] = velocity[1];`? Should that be `position[0] = position[1];` ?

Comment: you should close the file before returning the function.

Comment: @mustafagonul or simply don't close it at all, `ofstream`'s destructor does that for you!

Comment: As an engineer, I know that an exponential decay and an harmonic oscillation are very close connected, by Euler's formula. `exp(i*x) = cos(x)+i sin(x)`. In electrical engineering, a pure oscillation can be made with an LC circuit (R=0) and an exponential decay with an RC circuit (L=0) or an LR (C=0). Have all three non-zero and youn get a decaying oscillation. For your kinetic example, you shouldn't have a resistance effect, but the decay suggests you do.